# PowerShell script - Extract, Copy and delete zip file not working

Tags: java, powershell, powershell-2.0

> I have build a Power Shell script which should do the following

1. create java version directory if not exists
2. Download text file from intranet
3. Check java version from downloaded text file
4. If version not same download java zip file online
5. Extract the java zip file
6. Copy the JDK zip file to C:\Program Files\Java
7. Delete the zip file after extraction

> Below is my Power Shell script

```
$JavaVersion = "java.version=11.0.6"
$Folder = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java"
$IntranetUrl = http://10.1.48.25/test/version.txt
$IntranetTextFile = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\version.txt"
$JavaDownloadPath = http://10.1.48.25/test/install/Inst_20.05.00.01/testDesktop/OpenJDK11U- 
jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.6_10.zip
$JavaZipFilePath = C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\openjdk-11+28_windows-x64_bin.zip
$ExpandArchivePath = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\*.zip"
$ExpandArchiveDestinationPath = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java"

# create java version directory in C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java if it does not exist

if (-not (Test-Path $Folder)) {

try {
    New-Item -Path $Folder -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null #-Force
 }
catch {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to create directory "C:\Program Files\test". Error was: $_" - 
ErrorAction Stop
}
} 

# Download text file from intranet 
Invoke-WebRequest http://10.1.48.25/test/version.txt -OutFile 
"C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\version.txt"

# Check java version from version.txt
If (Get-Content $IntranetTextFile  | %{$_ -match $JavaVersion}) 
{
echo Version Same
}
else
{
# Download Java file 
Invoke-WebRequest $JavaDownloadPath -OutFile $JavaZipFilePath
}

#Extract the zip file in C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\jdk-11.0.6

if (-not (Test-Path "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\jdk-11")) {
Expand-Archive "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\openjdk-11+28_windows-x64_bin.zip" -DestinationPath 
"C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java"
}

# Copy the JDK zip file to C:\Program Files\Java
Copy-Item -Path .\*.zip -Destination $ExpandArchiveDestinationPath -force

#Delete the zip file after extraction
Remove-Item $JavaZipFilePath -Force
```

> My problem is:

1. when java version is same above script is downloading java zip file which I didn't want!

> The aim was to check if version same then display "Same Version" 
>   if not, download zip file

2. When version not same it is not extracting the zip file, not copying the file and not deleting it.

> I'm completely new to power shell any idea about how I can solved above issues.

Answer (score 0):

If it is downloading anyway, then the validation is not functioning as expected.

I made a few changes, as you can see, some syntax fixups, etc.

Yet, of course, I can't test this as I don't know what is in your $IntranetTextFile, nor do I have a similar environment to check against.

```
$JavaVersion                  = 'java.version=11.0.6'
$Folder                       = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java"
$IntranetUrl                  = 'http://10.1.48.25/test/version.txt'
$IntranetTextFile             = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\version.txt"
$JavaDownloadPath             = 'http://10.1.48.25/test/install/Inst_20.05.00.01/testDesktop/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.6_10.zip'
$JavaZipFilePath              = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\openjdk-11+28_windows-x64_bin.zip"
$ExpandArchivePath            = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\*.zip"
$ExpandArchiveDestinationPath = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java"

# create java version directory in C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java if it does not exist

if (-not (Test-Path $Folder)) 
{
    try 
    {
        New-Item -Path $Folder -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop | 
        Out-Null #-Force
    }
    catch 
    {
        $WriteErrorSplat = @{
            Message     = "Unable to create directory C:\Program Files\$Folder. Error was: $_"
            ErrorAction = 'Stop'
        }
        Write-Error @WriteErrorSplat
    }
} 

# Download text file from intranet 
$InvokeWebRequestSplat = @{
    Uri     = 'http://10.1.48.25/test/version.txt'
    OutFile = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\version.txt"
}
Invoke-WebRequest @InvokeWebRequestSplat

# Check java version from version.txt
If ((Get-Content $IntranetTextFile) -match $JavaVersion) 
{Write-Warning -Message 'Java Version already exits. Download not needed.'}
else {Invoke-WebRequest $JavaDownloadPath -OutFile $JavaZipFilePath}

#Extract the zip file in C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\jdk-11.0.6

if (-not (Test-Path "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\jdk-11")) 
{
    $ExpandArchiveSplat = @{
        Path            = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java\openjdk-11+28_windows-x64_bin.zip" 
        DestinationPath = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\test\java"
    }
}
Expand-Archive @ExpandArchiveSplat

# Copy the JDK zip file to C:\Program Files\Java
Copy-Item -Path '.\*.zip' -Destination $ExpandArchiveDestinationPath -force

#Delete the zip file after extraction
Remove-Item $JavaZipFilePath -Force
```